# airflow unit test operators which rely on command line parameters

Tags: unit-testing, parameters, airflow

Airflow allows one to pass parameters to dags via command line or via an experimental rest api. For example:

```
 airflow trigger_dag dag_id --conf '{"parameter":"~/path" }
```

A commonly referenced unit test example for an operator looks like this:
https://bcb.github.io/airflow/testing-dags

```
class TestMyOperator(TestCase):

    def test_execute(self):
        dag = DAG(dag_id='foo', start_date=datetime.now())
        task = MyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='foo')
        ti = TaskInstance(task=task, execution_date=datetime.now())
        result = task.execute(ti.get_template_context())
        self.assertEqual(result, 'foo')
```

How should one mock command line parameters in a unit test like the one above?

Comment: How do you retrieve the parameters in MyOperator? Could you add a constructor argument, that the DAG will inject, but the test will inject something else?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, the arguments are not available in the context of the dag, but only in the context of the operator and even then only in the context of a dag run. Can you work with arguments at the dag level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to make the parameter a template

Edit your MyOperator to something along these lines:

```
class MyOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ('parameter')

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
                 parameter,
                 *args,
                 **kwargs):

        super(MyOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parameter = parameter
```

And in your DAG:

```
my_operator = MyOperator(dag=dag, 
                 parameter="{{ dag_run.conf['parameter'] }}")
```

In your unittest just set the parameter

Unfortunately I have not tested this in a DAG, but according to various google searches this should work. On the plus side, this makes your MyOperator more independent and can be reused other places where the DAG is not instantiated through trigger_dag

I don't know if it is possible to set configurations during a test, as you would alter a dag_run. But you could browse through Airflows test-code and you might find something: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/tree/master/tests